# Trying to make a google sheet embed auto size (without scrolling) on the webpage

Tags: html, css, google-sheets, embed

I've tried using fit-content, fill-content, height="100%", and height="auto"
I'm not sure if this is possible, but if it's not google definitely should try and figure out a way to make it work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe
        src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vR-p4uEH_VDK55IPAhz94TLM03oZ40dis2blDnH_vm31QC8BaqqO0VvZU9c3u_EHS0WB8z1O92NDiae/pubhtml?gid=0&amp;single=true&amp;widget=true&amp;headers=false"
        width="100%" height="fill-content"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the style of an external iframe with internal CSS. Like many other Google embeds, Google Sheets does not give you the option to make the embed responsive.

Answer (score 4):

If you want your `iframe` to fill the height of the window, you will need to specify the height as a style, i.e. `style="height: 100vh;"` instead of  as an attribute.

```html
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vR-p4uEH_VDK55IPAhz94TLM03oZ40dis2blDnH_vm31QC8BaqqO0VvZU9c3u_EHS0WB8z1O92NDiae/pubhtml?gid=0&amp;single=true&amp;widget=true&amp;headers=false" width="100%" style="height: 100vh;"></iframe>
```

Comment: No, I don't want it to be the whole page I want its size to grow and shrink depending on its contents. So I don't have to scroll to see all the information.

Comment: In that case @WhyEvenContribute has your answer.

Comment: While it's not the answer you're looking for, setting `<iframe style="width:100%" ...>` inside a responsive `div` definitely improves the look and functionality of the embed. It prevents the possibility of needing to horizontally scroll two separate elements.